# how to merge two array in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two dynamic arrays. I tried two merge both. I used angular.extend and .concat function. But It does not work for me. Can anyone help me out from this? My sample array is here

```
 "first_data": [                             
            [
                "JSP",
                4463
            ],               
            [
                "JAVA",
                2022
            ]
        ],



          "second_data": [                              
            [
                "JSP",
                2483
            ],
            [
                "HTTP CONNECTION",
                43224
            ],
            [
                "JS",
                27413
            ]
        ]
```

My output should be like this.

```
 "output_data": [                              
            [
                "JSP",
                4463,
                2483
            ],               
            [
                "JAVA",
                2022,
                null
            ],
             [
                "HTTP CONNECTION",
                null,
                43224
            ],
            [
                "JS",
                null,
                27413
            ]
        ]
```

Comment: Neither of those two functions do what you're expecting. The closest I know of is Lodash's 'uniq' method, but it won't quite do what you want either. The logic you're pursuing isn't a standard merge - you want the resulting data to follow a template that can't be derived from your source data structure without some sort of custom parsing logic. You'll need to write a function to handle this, but it could make use of the lodash function I mentioned.

Comment: without using any logic is there any default method is there for merging like this dynamic map array??

Comment: Not without using any logic...no. You clearly need to do some comparing. That being said creating objects with the common field as keys would help

Comment: Check this function: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37797624/4989081

Comment: Show an example of how you was tried to merge these arrays.

Comment: @VijayVishnu I believe zipping array functions exist in languages like python, however, not JavaScript. In any case, your use case is quite bespoke. Using ES5 functions, I have created a zip function tailored to your requirement and added it as an answer below. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you require is known in functional programming terms as a zipped array. The function below will zip your arrays as per your example.

Use it like this `var newArray = zipArrays(arrays.first_data,arrays.second_data);`

```
var zipArrays = function(array_one, array_two) {

    //first take the first array and map any id from the second array to it
    var result = array_one.map(

      function(arrayItem) {
        //default setting = not found
        var found = -1;

        //search the second array for the current item in the first array
        array_two.forEach(function(secondArrayItem, index) {
          if (arrayItem[0] === secondArrayItem[0]) {
            found = index;
          }
        });

        //if we have found a match from the second array, add the id from the second array to the corresponding item in the first array
        if (found !== -1) {
          arrayItem.push(array_two[found][1]);
        } else {
          //no match in the second array, so add id as null
          arrayItem.push(null);
        }

        return arrayItem;
      }
    );

  //search the second array for items not in the first array
  array_two.forEach(

    function(arrayItem) {

      var found = -1;

      //the search of the first array              
      result.forEach(function(resultItem, index) {
        if (arrayItem[0] === resultItem[0]) {
          found = index;
        }

      });

      //item wasn't in the first array, so we'll add it to our results, and add null as the first id (since it wasn't in the first array)
      if (found === -1) {
        arrayItem.splice(1, 0, null);
        result.push(arrayItem);
      }
    }
  );

  return result;  

};
```

Here is the code in a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Bwre9HMAL1pnebGnJTlp?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Check this function:

```
mergeArrays = function(arr1, arr2) {
    var result = [];
    var array1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr1));
    var array2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr2));

    for (var ind1 = 0; ind1 < array1.length; ind1++) {
        result.push(array1[ind1]);
    }

    var wasInSecond = false;
    for (var ind1 = 0; ind1 < array1.length; ind1++) {
        wasInSecond = false;

        for (var ind2 = 0; ind2 < array2.length; ind2++) {
            if (array1[ind1][0] == array2[ind2][0]) {
                result[ind1].push(array2[ind2][1]);
                wasInSecond = true;
            }
        }
        if (!wasInSecond) {
            result[ind1].push(null);
        }
    }

    var wasInFirst = false;
    for (var ind2 = 0; ind2 < array2.length; ind2++) {
        wasInFirst = false;
        for (var ind1 = 0; ind1 < array1.length; ind1++) {
            if (array2[ind2][0] === array1[ind1][0]) {
                wasInFirst = true;
            }
        }
        if (!wasInFirst) {
            var toAdd = [array2[ind2][0], null, array2[ind2][1]];
            result.push(toAdd);
        }
    }

    return result;
};
```

See working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4a7f864a/) and play with included unit tests.

Comment: Have you tried [LODASH](https://lodash.com/docs) library. It really makes these kind of operation very easy as it provides several interactive features that angularjs don't provide. It is just an addon to angularjs. Find some time to look into this libraby. I am sure you will definitely like it.